# "Оружие" и "наружу", можно ли считать родственными эти слова?

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

По сути вопрос в заголовке, но хотелось бы узнать и о происхождении этих понятий.

Answer (score 1):

Если смотреть этимологические словари, то указанные Вами слова **не родственны**. Цитирую по словарю Шанского:

*Наружу:*

> Сращение предл.-пад. формы *на ружу*, где *ружу* — вин. п. ед. ч. от *ружа*
> «внешность, вид».

*Оружие:*

> Суф. производное от orǫzь *«кол, палка»* (ср. в др.-рус. яз. *оружь* —
> тж.), того же корня, что *рог*.

(Отголоском второго случая осталось нередко встречающееся в современном русском языке чередование *"г"-"ж"*, например *бере**г**у-бере**ж**ёшь*, *стро**г**ий*-*стро**ж**е*).

Comment: Вероятно, "рожа" разговорное производное от "ружа", или всё же от "рога - рожки"? Таким ещё вопросом задался, читая ваш ответ. И ещё одно понимание пришло, благодаря ему: рога - оружие по сути, орогатиться - орожиться - вооружиться... Спасибо!

Comment: @Аллазар нет, Фасмер особо подчёркивает, что "рожа" не родственна "наружности". "Рожа", по-видимому, была просто "лицом", причём скорее красивым, отсюда слово *немилорожий* «некрасивый лицом» и слово *рожаистъ* «красивый, видный». Почему "рожа" обзавелась значением "некрасивое лицо"? Предполагают, что из-за болезни "рожа" (которая так произносится по-польски и так вошла в русский язык). Название болезни по-польски означает "роза" (из-за специфического цвета болячки), а в русском два смысла слова "рожа" склеились.

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо за разъяснения.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще говоря, установить истинное родство слов можно по и.-е. корню (обычно без согласной).

**У слова "оружие"** в словаре Черных просматривается исходное значение корня. С одной стороны, родственная связь со словом "ругать" (в значении гнуть, кривить, изгибать), с другой — несомненная контаминация со словом "орудие" (также орудовать, действовать, рядить, связывать).

**По поводу слова "наружу"** информации у Черных нет. Но по Фасмеру очевидно, что есть связь с глаголами группы видеть, наблюдать:  "родств. латышск. raũgs «глазное яблоко, зрачок», raũdzît «видеть, смотреть, проверять, обращать внимание».

Общим значением может быть "связывать" (реально или путем наблюдения), но подобные выводы могут делать только лингвисты-этимологи.